# Can halide be a sigma donor?

Tags: coordination-compounds, ligand-field-theory

When I took inorganic classes, I was told that halide is a pi donor. Assume I am using metal hexahalide why I can't put the $p_z$ orbital of the halides directing to the metal centre? With that halide will just act as a sigma donor.

Comment: The two are not exclusive. Just because halides are pi donors does not mean they aren't sigma donors. If you orient the pz to be a sigma donor, px and py can also be pi donors.

Comment: Most ligands have both sigma and pi actions, involving different orbitals on both the ligand and the metal. Hydride is really the only exception, being sigma-only with the hydrogen 1s orbital.